# Angular función click error

Tags: angular

Si en angular en el HTML realizo esto y en la tabla se visualiza bien por que en el componente me da

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Peso' of undefined

```
  <table class="table table-light">
            <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr>

              <th>Peso</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let item of DataNN|filterBy:userFilter">
                <td>
                {{item.Peso}}
              </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
          </div>

          <button class="btn-primary"  (click)="ejecutar(item.Peso)"
```

Componente a partir de aquí

```
ejecutar (item) { 
   console.log(item.Peso)
}
```

Comment: consol.log (DataNN) me da esto:(114) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},…]
[0 … 99]
0: {IDTAG: 411615882, Peso: 277}
1: {IDTAG: 365243913, Peso: 202.5}
2: {IDTAG: 409477206, Peso: 230}

Answer (score 1):

Eso se debe a que `item.Peso` solo existe dentro del `<tr>` donde se está ejecutando el *ngFor.

Tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of DataNN|filterBy:userFilter">
     <td>
        {{item.Peso}}
     </td>
     <td>
        <button class="btn-primary"  (click)="ejecutar(item.Peso)"></button>
      </td>
</tr>
```

[ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kv6mcv)

Comment: y en el componente lo recupero asi?                                             
 ejecutar(item){ 
console.log(item.Peso)
} por que asi me da error  ejecutar(item.Peso){ ....

Comment: core.js:15714 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Peso' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (PesajeComponent.ngfactory.js:499)
    at Object.handleEvent ...... también persiste el error

Comment: Agregué ejemplo